# How to filter list in python based on index value?

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, indexing

Let's say I have 2 lists documenting the number of apples each person eats per day:

people = ['George', 'George', 'George', 'Dana', 'John', 'John']

apples_eaten = [5, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3]

In this scenario, we have 3 days of data from George, 1 day of data from Dana, and 2 days of data from John.

I want to know if there is a code that can filter the data based on the 'people' list, such that I can pull George's data with the output [5, 1, 3].

I wonder if there's a way to do this more easily if I have this data in matrix format with each data set being a row such that the indices are lined up? I am pulling these lists from a csv file but I wonder if I should just pull the entire data set from the csv file as a matrix.

Specifically looking for code WITHOUT loops, because I can easily code this with a loop, but I just want to avoid it since my data sets are huge and I already have a few loops in my code, so I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible.

EDIT:
The reason I want to minimize loops is because I have 4000 "people" I need to sort through, let's say numbers 1-4000, with around 11,000 data points I need to map these people to.

The loop I was thinking of was something like this:

```
unique_list = [] # list of people with unique IDs numbered 1-4000 
people = [] # list of 11,000 repeated ID numbers matching up with data points
data = [] # list of 11,000 data points 

 for i in len(unique_list) 
   data_sorted = []
   ID = unique_list[i]
   for x in len(data) 
       if people[x] = ID 
           data_sorted.append(data[x]) 
       else
```

So the reason I wanted to avoid this is because with the amount of data I have, it would take forever, and I just don't think this is the most efficient code. Let me know what y'all think, thanks!

Comment: You won't really be able to do anything without a loop here. Why the restriction on loops?

Comment: Any method you choose will implicitly or explicitly use loops.

Comment: If you need to look up one person once, then looping over 4000 items is nothing. If you need to look up different people over and over, that's obviously going to compound. So use a loop to transform the data into a more usable data structure _once_ (like a dict), and then look up data within that quickly as often as you need to.

Comment: To build a dictionary from 4,000 element *people* and *apples_eaten* lists takes 0.0004 seconds on Apple Silicon M2 (Python 3.12.0). That's probably representative of an "average" system. In other words, your 4,000 item dataset is really small and quite insignificant. Why you think using loops might be inefficient warrants explanation

Comment: @Codist FWIW, an M2 is really not average… But yeah, the point stands. ;)

Comment: So you rule out loops just because your own super-bad attempt uses loops?

Answer (score 1):

"Without loops" is a nonsensical condition here. Loops are unavoidable when the data has no structure to take advantage of. The only sane way to do this is with a loop; the few alternatives to loops will have to do all the same work with extra steps, likely in a *less* efficient manner. If you don't see a loop, it's because the loop was hidden behind an API that looped for you.

With that aside, the solution for a *single* lookup is a listcomp over `zip`:

```
people = ['George', 'George', 'George', 'Dana', 'John', 'John']

apples_eaten = [5, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3]

person_data = [cnt for person, cnt in zip(people, apples_eaten) if person == 'George']
```

That's it. There's a loop. It's part of a listcomp, which is heavily optimized by CPython. `zip` itself is also heavily optimized for this case (when the `tuple` it produces is unpacked each time, it reuses the *same* `tuple`, so no allocations occur). It'll be fine for looking up single people at once in data of any size, but you'll be doing `O(n)` work for each person you look up, so it doesn't scale well if you need to look up multiple people or *all* the people in the data.

If you might need to look up multiple people, and the data rarely changes, you can do some work up-front to make each individual lookup cheaper. The simplest solution is making a `dict` of `list`s mapping each person to their associated data, e.g.:

```
from collections import defaultdict  # At top of file

person_to_eaten_count = defaultdict(list)

for person, cnt in zip(people, apples_eaten):
    person_to_eaten_count[person].append(cnt)

# Optionally convert back to plain `dict` to prevent future autovivification of keys
person_to_eaten_count = dict(person_to_eaten_count)
```

Once you've made that `dict` (costing not much more than the search for a single person's data; it's `O(n)` to build the `dict`, just with slightly higher constant factors), looking up data for *any* person becomes ridiculously cheap; `person_to_eaten_count['George']` will get the data for `George` with `O(1)` work, and you can do the same for any other person as well.

Answer (score -1):

If your people names are always consecutive and unique, you could use the groupby function to build a dictionary out of the source lists:

```
people = ['George', 'George', 'George', 'Dana', 'John', 'John']
apples_eaten = [5, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3]

from itertools import groupby
iPeople     = iter(people)
data_sorted = {p:g for p,(*g,) in
               groupby(apples_eaten,key=lambda _:next(iPeople))}

print(data_sorted)

{'George': [5, 1, 3], 'Dana': [4], 'John': [3, 3]}
```

If the names are not necessarily consecutive, you could use a dictionary update to organize the result by name:

```
data_sorted = dict()
data_sorted.update( (p,data_sorted.get(p,[])+[a]) 
                    for p,a in zip(people,apples_eaten) )

print(data_sorted)

[('George', [5, 1, 3]), ('Dana', [4]), ('John', [3, 3])]
```

Comment: Unnecessarily complex. Deliberately esoteric. See @ShadowRanger's answer

Answer (score -2):

Its like this:

```
people = ['George', 'George', 'George', 'Dana', 'John', 'John']
apples_eaten = [5, 1, 3, 4, 3, 3]
dict1={}
i=0
for p in people:
    if p in dict1.keys():
        dict1[p].append(int(apples_eaten[i]))
    else:
        dict1[p]=list([])
        dict1[p].append(int(apples_eaten[i]))
    i+=1 
print(dict1)
```

output:

```
{'George': [5, 1, 3], 'Dana': [4], 'John': [3, 3]}
```

Comment: No need for the `.keys()` call, `if p in dict1:` is equivalent and avoids constructing an unnecessary view. No need to call `int` on the values from `apples_eaten`, they're already `int`s. `list([])` is ridiculous; `[]` gave you an empty `list`, why are you make a new empty `list` from it? And manual indexing is equally silly; even if you needed an index, you'd just use `for i, p in enumerate(people):` and have Python generate it for you (no `i=0`, no `i+=1`); since you *don't* need the index, you'd just `zip` the inputs together. This is about as unidiomatic as it gets without being *wrong*.

Comment: @ShadowRanger The required output has arrived !!! No issues!!